# Openfire - set admin GUI to listen on port 80

Tags: centos, xmpp, port, openstack, openfire

I am working on centos. I have installed openfire for an XMPP server. I am using a virtual machine on Openstack (public server with a floating IP). Due to restrictions and an ACL, port 9090 or 9091 is not available for ingress traffic. The only ports that are configured are 80 and 443.

I have tried to configure the iptables by opening port 80, but, this does not seem to make a difference. Even without port 80 being added to the iptable, it still comes up as being `open` when I check it using: https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Therefore, I am trying set openfire admin to listen on port 80 from the cofiguration file, since, of course, I cannot connect to the admin GUI to change it from there. The machine has an Apache web server, which by default listens on port 80. I turned this off using:

```
sudo service httpd stop
```

When I look at `netstat -tulpn | grep 80`, I can see that nothing is listening on port 80, so I can assume nothing else is using port 80.

I changed the `openfire.xml` in `opt/openfire/conf/`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    This file stores bootstrap properties needed by Openfire.
    Property names must be in the format: "prop.name.is.blah=value"
    That will be stored as:
        <prop>
            <name>
                <is>
                    <blah>value</blah>
                </is>
            </name>
        </prop>

    Most properties are stored in the Openfire database. A
    property viewer and editor is included in the admin console.
-->
<!-- root element, all properties must be under this element -->
<jive>
    <adminConsole>
        <!-- Disable either port by setting the value to -1 -->
        <port>80</port>
        <securePort>-1</securePort>
    </adminConsole>

    <locale>en</locale>

    <!-- Network settings. By default, Openfire will bind to all network interfaces.
      Alternatively, you can specify a specific network interfaces that the server
      will listen on. For example, 127.0.0.1. This setting is generally only useful
       on multi-homed servers. -->
    <!--
    <network>
        <interface></interface>
    </network>
    -->
</jive>
```

When I do `netstat -tulpn | grep 80` again, I don't see anything open on 80. I have read something about if openfire isn't started as root, then it cannot listen on anything below port range 1024. Therefore, I ensured I started openfire service with: `sudo service openfire start`.

Are there any configurations for openfire that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preroute your traffic so traffic coming in on port 80 to port 9090. I'm assuming that port 9090 is open.

You can open port 9090 like so:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9090 -j ACCEPT
```

Save your iptables rules:

```
sudo iptables-save
```

Then you can add the PREROUTING rule like so:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to 9090
```

Check your rules to see if was assigned correctly. Type:

```
iptables -t nat -L -n
```

Output should look something like this:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 redir ports 9090
```

Then restart the Openfire service:

```
sudo service openfire stop
sudo service openfire start
```

You can even change the port that Apache listens on just to be sure that nothing is using port 80.

You can change this if you go to `/etc/httpd/conf/` and then `sudo vi httpd.conf`. Once editing the file, you can change the port from 80 to another unused port e.g. 8080. Remember, the other port must be unused if you still want Apache to work.

For further reading on PREROUTING, read the following post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/579231/whats-the-difference-between-prerouting-and-forward-in-iptables